# How expensive is SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

What is the cost of calling SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters? I understand that a round-trip is required to the DB server to get the parameters. After this is called, will the information be cached by the provider, or will it be re-queried EVERY time this method is called?

Comment: See [this article](https://adamprescott.net/2012/09/24/sqlcommand-parameter-caching/) on adding Parameter Caching to `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the direction I was heading in.

Comment: David Hayden has revamped his blog; there is a cached version of the page at http://web.archive.org/web/20110701205001/http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/03/CachingStoredProcedureParameters.aspx

Comment: DeriveParameters calls a system sp which name starts with "sp_procedure_params_".

Comment: the earlier blog link is lost & this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/adonet-cookbook/0596004397/ch04s10.html) kind of explains similar issue...

Answer (score 2):

Calling DeriveParameters will require a DB call (every time). There is no integrated caching, you would have to implement this yourself.